# Printing final output from list of lists

Tags: python, list

Initially, i have a list of lists containing, for example

```
L = [[01,02],[03,04],[05,06]]
```

and for each of the individual list within the list of list, my program does some calculation from the elements within the list and had the values output in a single list.

```
OutputList = [2.1,2.2,2.3]
```

the value 2.1 corresponds to [01,02], 2.2 corresponds to [03,04] and finally 2.3 corresponds to [05,06]

i want to print out the outputList and also the individual list corresponding to the value in the output list something like as below.

```
2.1 : [01,02]
2.2 : [03,04]
2.3 : [05,06]
```

I would like to know how i would be able to get the output as such. I know i should utilise for loops to perform something like:

```
for val in OutputList:
    for lst in L:
        OutputList[val] == L[lst] ##??
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I iterate through two lists in parallel in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-can-i-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` to iterate `list` values with index

```
for ind, val in enumerate(outputList):
    print('{} : {}'.format(val, L[ind])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `zip` two lists together like `zip(outputList,L)` and it will create tuples like (2.1,[01,02]) , you can just print the list as below:

```
zipped =zip(outputList,L)
for item in :
     print ("{} : {}".format(zipped[0],zipped[1]))
```